# Using SQL WHERE LIKE to filter when have consecutive numbers

Tags: sql-server

Trying to convert a PostgreSQL view to SQL Server (2016) view.

I have a table with a column named filename, with the following data:

- R24bMP1.png
- MP3.png
- R28.jpg
- I002.jpg
- App_1472669569054.jpg
- Test_1575753047890.png

So, I like to filter all rows the filename must contains 13 consecutives numbers, in the example, only `App_1472669569054.jpg` and `Test_1575753047890.png`.

In PostgreSQL, I can use regex to do this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE filename ~ '\d{13}'`.

Tried in SQL Server with:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE filename LIKE '%[0-9]{13}%'`, but got no results. The only way that worked is:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE filename LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'`

After that, I need to get only the number part of filename, in the example, the returned value must be:

- 1472669569054
- 1575753047890

I know I can use CLR with SQL Server, but I like to known if is possible to filter without CLR in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Martin Smith pointed out:

```
'%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

can be reduced to:

```
'%' + replicate('[0-9]',13) + '%'
```

---

You were most of the way there:

```
declare @filename varchar(128) = 'Test_1575753047890.png'

select test=substring(@filename
  ,patindex('%' + replicate('[0-9]',13) + '%',@filename)
  ,13
  )
```

returns: `1575753047890`

---

So for your table it would look like:

```
select test=substring([filename]
  ,patindex('%' + replicate('[0-9]',13) + '%',[filename])
  ,13
  )
from t
where patindex('%' + replicate('[0-9]',13) + '%',[filename]) > 0
```

Comment: Or `patindex('%' + REPLICATE('[0-9]',13) + '%',@filename)` is a bit more concise.

Comment: @MartinSmith Very true!